# Concatenating files in Windows Command Prompt and the string "ï»¿"

Tags: windows, text, unicode, cmd, byte-order-mark

I am concatenating files using Windows.  I have used the TYPE and the COPY command and I get the same artifact.  At the place where my original files are joined in the new file, the character string "ï»¿" (i.e. Decimal: 139 175 168 Hex: 8BAFA8) is inserted.

How can I troubleshoot this?  Is there an easy explanation you can provide for how to avoid this. And why does this happen?

Comment: I'm guessing this is some kind of encoding specification, either a byte-order-mark or something similar denoting the type of encoding used for the following file. Most likely these characters exists as the first 3 characters in the file you appended at that point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding

Comment: Are you **sure** those are the bytes? The characters, `ï»¿` perfectly matches UTF-8 byte order mark, but that's different byte values.

Comment: I looked it up the ASCII table here http://www.asciitable.com/ .

Comment: I tried to google that...  So Windows 10 command prompt or the program I'm using to save the files uses or doesn't use Unicode?  That's a start.  Fascinating, thanks.

Comment: my mistake may be my assumption that the display was ASCII not UTF-8.

Comment: relavent: https://superuser.com/questions/1323635/windows-command-line-to-concatenate-multiple-utf-8-files-with-bom-using

Comment: You are looking at a table for one of the obsolete code pages that were used by MSDOS and are still emulated by the so-called 'DOS window' or 'DOS box' in Windows. But modern (since 2003) Windows programs like notepad use a different set of codepages -- for US and Western Europe usually [**code page 1252**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). In 1252, those three characters are EF BB BF which are the UTF8 for U+FEFF. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: and, It's the program creating the files.  thanks again!

Comment: ditto, for the code page 1252 link.

Comment: …or code page [65001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_65001)? Anyway, `type` does not change or convert anything as soon as redirection is used, so it is in binary mode then; `copy` features `/A` (ASCII text files) and `/B` (binary files) options, which you might want to play around with…

Comment: `I looked it up the ASCII table here` that's not the way to find out which bytes are in a file. You need to use a hex editor instead

Comment: and if you're running cmd.exe in Windows then **it's not DOS**. [DOS and cmd.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386) are completely different things so don't call it DOS if you don't actually run DOS. And who says "don't use DOS"? Command line is actually the preferred way to do many things because it's usually much more powerful than a GUI with many options that the GUI doesn't provide

Comment: DOS `copy` won't do it.  It doesn't know about UTF-8 or BOM and can only do binary append `copy /b file1+file2 file3`.

Answer (score 1):

The very good explanation why does this happen is in @Mark_Tolonen answer, so I will not repeat it.

Instead of obsolete TYPE and COPY one have to use powershell now:

```
powershell -Command "& { Get-Content a*.txt | Out-File output.txt -Encoding utf8 }"
```

This command get content of all files patterned by a*.txt in a current folder and concatenates them in the output.txt file using UTF-8.

Powershell is a part of Windows 7 and later.

Answer (score 0):

The extra bytes are a UTF-8 encoding signature.  The Unicode byte order mark U+FEFF is encoded in UTF-8 and written to the beginning of the file to indicate the file is encoded in UTF-8.  It's not required but Windows assumes a text file is encoded in the local ANSI encoding (commonly Windows-1252) unless a BOM appears.

Many file tools don't know about this (DOS copy being one of them), so concatenating files can be troublesome.

Today being ignorant of encodings often causes trouble.  You can't simply concatenate two text files of unknown encoding...they may be different.

If you know the encoding, use a tool that understands the encoding.  Here's a **very** basic concatenate script written in Python that will convert encodings as well.

```py
# cat.py
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 5:
    print('usage: cat <in_encoding> <out_encoding> <outfile> <infile> [infile...]')
else:  
    with open(sys.argv[3],'w',encoding=sys.argv[2]) as fout:
        for file in sys.argv[4:]:
            with open(file,'r',encoding=sys.argv[1]) as fin:
                fout.write(fin.read())
```

Given two files with UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding, this command will output UTF-8 (no BOM):

```
cat.py utf-8-sig utf-8 out.txt test1.txt test2.txt
```

Side note about Python: `utf-8-sig` encoding reads files and removes the BOM from the data *if present*, so it can be used to read any UTF-8 file with or without a BOM.  `utf-8-sig` encoding *writes* a BOM at the start of a file, but `utf-8` does not.